# How to set values from profile saved model after list items was loaded

Tags: xamarin.forms

Via api, I get a list of values stored in the user profile model also from the server I receive a general list (ItemSource) for the CollectionView element how to set the stored values in the  ItemSource list in which sequence to call API methods. Data are stored in different models.

I've tried via PropertyChanged but getting a loop

This my  itemsSource data for ViewModel

```
 private ObservableCollection<City> cityDTOs;


    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities

    {
        get { return cityDTOs; }
        set { SetProperty(ref cityDTOs, value); }
    }
```

This one is my profileModelView Property

```
   public ObservableCollection<City> SelectedCities { get; set; } = new 
 ObservableCollection<City>();
```

Comment: Add data one by one, once you completed the API call.

Comment: Thank you. I added my selectedCities values to CitiesViewModel as Property and after getting values cities from the server, forming collection correct with isSelected property, therefore Binding work excellent, but BeginInvokeOnMainThread work correct and EnableCollectionSynchronization doesn't work.